# How to SELECT records for the latest date in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

From the below table i want to write a select statement where i can select the price of the items for the
latest date.

```
Item  |  Price   | Date
------|----------|--------
1001  |   10      | 26-5-2019
1001  |   11      | 15-02-2020
1001  |   9       | 28-08-2020
1002  |   5       | 1/7/2019
1002  |   3       | 8/11/2019
1002  |   4       | 5/5/2020
1003  |   6       | 26-05-2019
1003  |   7       | 1/2/2020
1003  |   5       | 15-09-2020
```

Result should be as below:

```
Item  |  Price   | Date 
------|----------|-------- 
1001  |  9       | 28-08-2020 
1002  |  4       | 5/5/2020 
1003  |  5       | 15-09-2020
```

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the datatype of the date column? Seeing you provide us with different formats, I'm guessing its a varchar. If that's true it makes tasks like this extra hard.

Comment: i tried to use the below statement here it groups with the price column                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                
 select item,price, MAX(Date) as NewDate
 from Item-table
group by item,price

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that the table is unreadable and you haven't posted anything about what you have tried so far, I will try to help you...

You can get the price via Window Functions - in this case row_number. You should try something like the following:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT Item, Price, [Date], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS rn) x
WHERE x.rn = 1
```